# $SU(2)$ comparator in Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

When Peskin and Schroeder build the comparator for a local $SU(2)$ (chapter 15.2), they say that near $U=\mathbb{I}$ any $2\times 2$ unitary matrix can be expanded in terms of the Hermitian generators of $SU(2)$

$$U(x+\epsilon n,x)=\mathbb{I}+ig\epsilon n^\mu A_\mu^i\frac{\sigma^i}{2}+\mathcal O(\epsilon^2),\tag{15.23}$$

where $\mathbb{I}$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. However, this is not the most general expansion of a $2\times2$ unitary matrix, we could include the identity as a generator

$$U(x+\epsilon n,x)=\mathbb{I}+ig\epsilon n^\mu\Big( A_\mu^i\frac{\sigma^i}{2}+A_\mu^0\mathbb{I}\Big)+\mathcal O(\epsilon^2).$$

Why don't they include it? I know that physically that $A_\mu^0$ field shouldn't appear, but I don't see why we don't include it in this way of building the covariant derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The identity element is a generator of $U(2)$, but not of $SU(2)$.

The unitary matrix corresponding to the identity generator is
$$
U = \exp ( \frac{i}{2}\alpha  \mathbb{I}) = e^{i \alpha/2} \mathbb{I}
$$
This has
$$
\det U = e^{i\alpha}
$$
Elements of $SU(2)$ must satisfy $\det U = +1$ so we must set $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but they demand that $U(y,x)$ is just unitary (at least in my version), what they demand to be in $SU(2)$ is the gauge transformation, what they call $V(x)$.

Comment: He may use the phrase unitary, but he definitely means special unitary (at least in this context).

Answer (score 0):

Peskin and Schroeder are demanding here that $U(y,x)$ is not just unitary, but special-unitary, meaning its determinant is one. Your additional $A_{\mu}^0$ violates this condition. To see this, try writing $U(x + \epsilon n, x)$ in exponentiated form, where you can see that $A_{\mu}^0$ essentially determines the global phase of $U$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but they demand that $U(y,x)$ is just unitary (at least in my version), what they demand to be in $SU(2)$ is the gauge transformation, what they call $V(x)$.